# WinForms UserControl How Do I Stop the control receiving focus

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, user-controls

I have a custom `UserControl` that contains just one `TextBox`.

When I set the control to `Enabled = False`, the TextBox is disabled but the control is not (control still fires the `Enter` event).

How do I ensure that the `UserControl` will not receive focus?

My Enabled Property Looks like this:

```
Private _Enabled As Boolean = True

Public Shadows Property Enabled As Boolean
    Get
        Return _Enabled
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        _Enabled = value
        txtTime.Enabled = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: @Hans - the issue with removing it is that the TextBox does not enable / disable when the UserControl Enabled property is changed

Comment: That's rather vexing, Enabled always disables any child controls as well.  Careful with *Shadows*, it has a knack for byting back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your immediate question, you need to pass the enabled property to the base object:

```
public new bool Enabled {
    get { return _Enabled; }
    set {
        _Enabled = value;
        textBox1.Enabled = value;
        base.Enabled = value;
    }
}
```

However... the correct way to do it is using the `OnEnabledChanged` override:

```
protected override void OnEnabledChanged(EventArgs e) {
    textBox1.Enabled = this.Enabled;
    base.OnEnabledChanged(e);
}
```

(As you tagged it C#, I assume you can convert back to VB.net yourself)

Comment: Thanks - no problem converting it.

Answer (score 2):

Every control already has a property called Enabled. You don't have to create your own property to do that.

This property is inherited from the `Control` class, that is the base for every windows forms controls.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx